# Change Google Maps example Apps Scrpt from static map

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script

Using Google's example for creating a map from sheets but the map is static and I need it to be a fully functioning map, not an image.  Just don't know the change in code.  I DO have a Google Maps API to pay for use.

I've tried several things but clearly I don't know what I'm even reading so I won't go into it.

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
function sendMap() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var address = sheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var map = Maps.newStaticMap().addMarker(address);
  GmailApp.sendEmail('lisa@candleberry.com', 'Map', 'See below.', {attachments:[map]});
}
```

This app script does what it should, but I just need to know how to change it for the issue.

Comment: Email agents don't support live maps/html with JavaScript.

Comment: I don't need to see the live map in email.  I need it to give me a link to the live map.

Comment: [Edit] your question to make that clear

Answer (score 0):

To get a live url, you could use the [Maps url api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#search-action), which doesn't need any special access. You'd just need to format the url as

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&parameters
```

#### Snippet:

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
function sendMap() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var address = sheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var mapUrl = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=";
  var mapQuery = encodeURIComponent(address);
  GmailApp.sendEmail('recipient1@example.com', 'Map', 'Here\'s the live link:\n '+mapUrl+mapQuery );
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and what came back was, "Missing ) after argument list. (line 7, file "Code")", which is this line: GmailApp.sendEmail('recipient1@example.com', 'Map', 'Here's the live link:\n '+mapUrl+mapQuery );

Comment: @Lisa check now

Comment: This is what came back:  Script function not found: myFunction

Comment: @Lisa After editing, you need to save the file. Then run `sendMap`, not `myFunction`